# Why Omit from type of intersection with Record<string, any> makes all values any?

Tags: typescript

Why in [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQGcwpQBzAbhzwCMjTyRqsBfLLMATwAcUAQsgC8aZADJkAJQgIA9lAAmAHiaUANPhDcAfJ0WyANnCgpDEMMgbIBNLHQB0dKsgD0rkmUrIe-Tr5QAYRFkAHkAW2AwZQFNAHI4OJ07AwRjU2RzSwQiQLsEJxd3ZAB1AAtufBhIKDDIywDkORhkAAMCulbkUBhoYnx+1rhtVqwgA) example type of `c.b` infers as `any`

```
interface A {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

type B = A & Record<string, any>

declare let b: B;

b.b; // string type

type C = Omit<B, 'a'>;

declare let c: C;

c.b; // Why after Omit type of `c.b` infers as `any`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens the way `Omit` works.

Lets look at how it's defined:

```
type Omit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; }
```

You see that it uses `Exclude<keyof T, K>` to defines the keys.

In our case here we have

```
type Keys = Exclude<keyof B, 'a'> // string.
```

and the keys are more precisely defined by :

```
keyof ({ 'a': string } & Record<string, any>)
```

which results to `string`.

Therefore it will match the values from `Record<string, any>` : `any`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQGcwpQBzAbhzwCMjTyRqsBfLLMATwAcUAQsgC8aZADJkAJQgIA9lAAmAHiaUANPhDcAfJx79kAYRHIA8gFtgYZQM0ByOPZ00si2QBs4UFB4hhkBCIjVwQAOjosAHoogD0Afk4Y5AMUS2tlABVNAGlkCAAPSBBFYhIySmQAH2QQAFcLOmhqkm5GuQ8dUwxkAG0ABWRQZABRAoQPOvdlAGsIbjkYZGzkHJ0AXSJMgfWqZA59PhQYOTlTMYmpiFn5xeQ7ZEdnZGS1FiA)

Comment: Why in my example it happens only after "Omit" operation?

Comment: You made a great point, I totally edited my answer !

Comment: Now it remains to understand whether this is a bug or a feature)

Comment: You mean you would expect `type a = keyof ({ 'a': string } & Record<string, any>)` to be anything else than `string` ?

Comment: I understand why this is so. But I would like Omit to work a little more as expected. 
Anyway thank you )